# Keep row permanently selected in the ListView in Win32

Tags: c, listview, winapi, mfc, selection

I am using Win32 ListView32.

When row in the *ListView* is selected it has dark blue color.
The row can be selected by either clicking on it or programmatically by calling `ListView_SetItemState(hwnd, index, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);`.

When *ListView* control focus is lost the selected row becomes gray.

How can I keep selected row with dark blue color irrespective of the focus?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window style. I don't think it can stay as dark blue as that's the indicator that that control has focus.

Comment: If it is showing grey at the moment, then the list view already has the `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` style.

Comment: You need change the color of the row. It is already selected.

Answer (score 1):

"Presumably you're doing this in a OnInitDialog handler? If so, you need
to SetFocus to your list control, and return FALSE from OnInitDialog."

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VC6.0. You can set properties as "Show selection always" to ListView. And ListView will be defined by VC6.0 as `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`.

The definition of the CONTROL in resource file looks like:

```
CONTROL         "List2",IDC_LIST_MEMBER,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | 
                LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_EDITLABELS | WS_BORDER | 
                WS_TABSTOP,7,64,514,187
```

And The selected item will be highlighted. For my program, the default background color is white, the default selected and focused color is blue, and the default selected but lost focused color is gray(when usr click to other control).